# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.109.0 - Why does it search for version 1.0.109.0 when I have referenced 1.0.109.1

Tags: .net, sqlite, asp.net-core

I have created new `ASP.NET Core Web Application` and used `ASP.NET Core 2.1` cross platform framework.

Next, I added `System.Data.SQLite.Core` using `Nuget manager`. It's the official SQLite database engine for both x86 and x64 along with the ADO.NET provider.

My Main method

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("abc");
    }
```

When I run the application, it's trying to search for  **1.0.109.0** instead of installed `1.0.109.1` version.

So end up throwing below exception as expected

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>     HResult=0x80070002
>     Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.109.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     Source=

So, why it's searching for wrong version?

**Screenshots for reference**

[image]

[image]

My Solution platform is "Any CPU" and I'm running on a x64 Windows 7 on an x64

**Strange**

When I do **F12** on `SQLiteConnection` class, it goes to

[image]

My .csproj file conent

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
     <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.109.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this exact same issue. What ended up working for me was:

1. In Windows Explorer, navigate to `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages`
2. Delete the directories for `system.data.sqlite.core` and `system.data.sqlite.core`
3. In your `.csproj`, change your sqlite package reference to

   ```
   `<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.109.0"/>`
   ```
4. Rebuild the project to restore the package

Comment: wow, it worked!  But is it right way to do it? are we going to get all benefits from 1.0.109.1? or is it still pointing to 1.0.109.0 . Anyway let me mark it as answer because I do not think there is no other way around.

Comment: yes it's a bit of a workaround. It seems to me the right way might be a fix from the sqlite folks, but I'm not sure. I went digging around in the %UserProfile% directories before trying this and noticed the dlls in lib that were installed with 109.1 were actually versioned 109.0. I didn't think this mattered as long as the nuspec was properly configured, but my experience creating nuspecs is exactly 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think **1.0.109.0** has been obsolete and no longer available on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core) You can go to

> .csproj

Inside **ItemGroup**

check the version number of [system.Data.SQlite.Core](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki).
If it is using **1.0.109.0** then replace it with **1.0.109.1**

I have a project in which you can see versions are same in both .csproj and references
[image]

if you are not using [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) you can find .csproj file by right click on project and select Open Folder in File Explorer

Since you have version **1.0.109.1** of **[System.Data.SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core)** not **[System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite)**

```
Install-Package System.Data.SQLite -Version 1.0.109.1
```

Comment: csproj is having Version="1.0.109.1"

Comment: I already have -Version 1.0.109.1, why should I run command again?

Comment: you have version of System.Data.SQLite.Core not System.Data.SQLite

Comment: I have added both and still has same error. :(  did u get chance to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Asp.Net Core 2.0, and the only thing that helped was using 1.0.108.

Comment: It looks like that version is no longer available on nuget. Can you elaborate on how you installed it?

Comment: where I can find 1.0.108?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - manually editing the .csproj file worked - but so did going through the NuGet VS.Code plugin, which did offer me 1.0.108.