# Why SQLite crash in UWP with cannot find the file specified?

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I install the SQLite from Nuget as below:
[image]

And after I ran the program it throws this error:
[image]

I feel strange that it showed the Version is 1.0.109.0 but not the version I installed which 1.0.109.2

What's more, I tried the way what [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.109.0 - Why does it search for version 1.0.109.0 when I have referenced 1.0.109.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069231/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite-version-1-0-109-0-why-doe)
said

But all the way no works.

In addition, I opened the `.csproj` and here is the SQLite package reference:
[image]

The version in `.csproj` is right.

What's wrong with it.Would you please tell me how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Install the `sqlite` package instead of the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` package and make sure that the `SQLite` assembly gets copied to your output directory.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for reminding me that the SQLite assembly gets copied to my output directory. I embed the SQLite in a dll and runs it in a UWP program. The UWP program does not embed SQLite yet. After I embed it, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `SQLite` assembly gets copied to your output directory so it can be found at runtime. It should if you install the `SQLite` package in your UWP app project.